# How can I ensure that .NET 4.5 is installed on a Puppet agent?

Tags: .net, puppet, chocolatey

I am trying to ensure that .NET 4.5 is installed on an agent.  I am using the puppet-chocolatey provider:

```
package { 'DotNet4.5':
    ensure          => installed,
    provider        => 'chocolatey',
}
```

However, each time I run it, the log shows 1 change:

> *Notice: /Stage[main]//Node[mymachine1234]/Package[DotNet4.5]/ensure: created*

Even though .NET 4.5 is installed, it still reports that 1 change has occurred as shown above.

I have also tried the value of `4.5` instead of `installed` in the definition above, but whatever I apply it reports 1 change.

In contrast, when I use the same thing to ensure Node.js is installed, it works just fine and doesn't report 1 change each time.

I'm open to any other ways of ensuring that .NET 4.5 is installed.

Comment: Puppet is a Linux tool.  It isn't very clear to me exactly what you are installing, but you might be ahead by tagging this question with [mono] instead.

Comment: Puppet works on [Windows](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Puppet_Windows) as well, in this case we have a puppet agent on a Windows server box.  The [modules](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/tags/windows) usually use Powershell and command prompt instead.

Comment: @HansPassant You are living in the past my friend. Puppet and Windows have been a thing since 2011. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is likely a bug in a way that we are getting back information from chocolatey and processing it. So we see DotNet4 but not DotNet4.5. I see you already filed a bug (https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey/issues/19), thank you. We can continue the conversation there. :)

UPDATE: This has been fixed, so expect to see a bump on the forge soonish.